# Entries of all users show regardless of who has logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first rails project. Currently, I have a page that should only show the entries that were added by the logged in user.

Here is what the page looks like. Most of the entries at the top are random just to make sure it was accepting from the form.

I created another account and realized that I could still see entries from the other account.

Here: 
https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAuv4k7k

Currently, I have the controller set as

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @persons = Person.all
  end

  def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

I looked around and suspect that'll have to do something like this but I'm not sure where to put the code.

I Tried the following:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:persons, :comicbooks]
```

Also, For collecting the posts of a specific user, I tried this:

```
@persons = current_user.persons
```

Here is the error I get:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8uXw1y6

Here is the persons_controller.rb:
https://share.getcloudapp.com/JruWwndN

--
All help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of images of code, please include the code as text in your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have a has many association between user and persons?  In your image you're using the class name `Person` instead of  `persons`.

Comment: `For collecting the posts of a specific user` With your statements I conclude it should be 
`@person = current_user
@posts = current_user.posts`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing,
`before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:persons, :comicbooks]` is not working. right syntax is `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]` or `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]` or just `before_filter :authenticate_user!`. It mean `authenticate_user!` method will be excute before execute `index`, `show` methods.

The second, if you want to collect the posts of a specific user, you need to ensure that you have been declared `has_many :posts` in user model. Then you can use `current_user.posts` to collect all post of specific user.

Answer (score 0):

From the pictures you shared you have a code in your controller with an instance variable:

```
@person = current_user.Person
```

This is wrong as `Person` does not belong to a `user` but rather `current_user.person`.

`current_user` is autoloaded globally so the `authenticate_user!` callback has no effect on it. 
Now to get all the posts for a specific, logged in user, you can use:

```
@posts = current_user.persons
```

The code you have on the last line of your question should work but I don't think it's the same as you have in the error screenshot you posted.